# Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

Hey I'm pretty new to university math and one of my assignments wants me to determine whether this formula converges or diverges.

My reasoning was that it is bigger than 1/n and that diverges. so it should diverge as well.

Comment: Think about replacing $n^n$ with $3^n.$ You're making the terms bigger (why?), but after doing so you get a convergent geometric series (why?).

Comment: thanks u2! sorry for asking the question again. didn't find it in my search